# In what format does Google Chrome store extension install dates

Tags: c#, google-chrome, datetime, google-chrome-extension

I am looking through the preferences file that Google Chrome uses for installed extensions and it would seem the install_time is stored in a weird format.

Here are a few sample dates from the file:

```
"install_time": "13018473436573431",

"install_time": "13018473437125431",
"lastpingday": "13024047600974141",
```

It does not convert to a DateTime in a C# application and it doesn't seem to be a normal javascript date(Those are only 13 numbers).

It's really weird that it is 17 numbers.

Here is some extra debug information, I output the date when I attempt to call new DateTime("install_date") and the number itself.

```
Program  Entry:
Ext Name: Clock
install_time: 1/2/0001 12:10:40 PM
install_time raw data: 13024070300259446
install_time (long):   13024070300259446

Program  Entry:
Ext Name: Googulator
install_time: 1/2/0001 12:10:40 PM
install_time raw data: 13024076154792655
install_time (long):   13024076154792655

Program  Entry:
Ext Name: Google News
install_time: 1/2/0001 12:10:40 PM
install_time raw data: 13024076389301659
install_time (long):   13024076389301659

Program  Entry:
Ext Name: Spotify - Music for every moment
install_time: 1/2/0001 12:10:40 PM
install_time raw data: 13024076418505659
install_time (long):   13024076418505659
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to know what dates those are supposed to represent?

Comment: They should approximately be today about an hour ago. I would say about 10:45AM 9/19/2013 Eastern Time.

Comment: Hmm then that rules out Unix epoch microseconds

Comment: Yeah, I tried simply parsing the values as type long and initializing the DateTime using that value as "ticks", but as you see from my results, that didn't work out.

Comment: [This is about the most useful thing](http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/decoding-google-chrome-timestamps-in.html) I have found so far, note the Chrome Time section. Might give you some ideas of what to look for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, think I might has worked it out, Well it certainly produce Today's date, you will need to work out if the time adds up. Consider the following javascrpt:

```
var installTime = 13024070300259446;
var convertedTime = ( installTime - 11644473600000000 ) / 1000 ;//divide by 1000 because we are going to add milliseconds on to the base date
var date = new Date(convertedTime);
alert(date);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/g2rne/)

The original formula was obtained [from here](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/01/21/google-chrome-forensics/):

> Ref the history SQL statement in the OP, it can be modded a bit to get
>   some human readable output from the timestamps. As already noted, the
>   timestamps are in Webkit format, so needs some tweaking to get
>   something intelligible.
>
> SELECT urls.url, urls.title, urls.visit_count, urls.typed_count,
>   datetime(((urls.last_visit_time-11644473600000000)/1000000),'unixepoch','localtime')
>   as last_visit_time, urls.hidden,
>   datetime(((visits.visit_time-11644473600000000)/1000000),'unixepoch','localtime')
>   as visit_time, visits.from_visit, visits.transition FROM urls, visits
>   WHERE urls.id = visits.url

However, the initial attempt of `/ 1000000` didn't work out, so I tried `/ 1000` instead and that did work! (see edit below as to why this didn't work)

---

For completeness, as you have specifically used the C# tag, here is the C# version:

```
long installTime = 13024070300259446;
long convertedTime = ( installTime - 11644473600000000 ) / 1000000 ;//divide by 1000000 because we are going to add Seconds on to the base date
DateTime date = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
date = date.AddSeconds(convertedTime);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

---

**EDIT**: After seeing Garrett's answer, it is clear why I had to divide by 1000 in my javascript example and he divides by 1000000 in his C# example. Because the javascript code is adding milliseconds onto the base date, where as C# is adding only seconds on to the base date. (NOTE: I have updated my C# code to reflect this)

Comment: Thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/LaLasd0y/ (for those who find alert(obnoxious lol))

Answer (score 0):

## Converting from Webkit time to DateTime

Thanks everybody for the help. After looking through the helpful links musefan linked, I was able to get an answer. It is a little different than musefan's. I also added comments for added clarity, just in case anyone needs help with this in the future.

Here is Musefan's source that I used: http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/decoding-google-chrome-timestamps-in.html

```
        //The install time was 12:20 PM
        long rawTime = 13024081249872950;
        //Subtract the amount of seconds from 1601 to 1970.
        long convertedTime = (rawTime - 11644473600000000);
        //Devide by 1000000 to convert the remaining time to seconds.
        convertedTime = convertedTime / 1000000;
        //Set up a date at the traditional starting point for unix time.
        DateTime normalDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        //Add the seconds we calculated above.
        DateTime googleDate = normalDate.AddSeconds(convertedTime);
        //Finally we have the date.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Final Date: " + googleDate.ToString());
```

Output:

Final Date: 9/19/2013 4:20:49 PM

It appears to be 4 hours off from -5 GMT (Eastern).

Comment: Ah, so dividing by 1000000 works in C#. That must be because the javascript example I used was working with milliseconds rather than seconds

Comment: Just for a reference, here is how one would convert a DateTime to a Webkit Date.


TimeSpan span = (date - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));

return ((long)span.TotalSeconds * 1000000) + 11644473600000000;

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert the install_time like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(1601,1,1).AddTicks(10 * installTime);
```

No need to work with any manual offset and divisions etc...